# GRUB reported “error: file not found.” when booting CentOS 5

Tags: linux, centos, grub2

I installed CentOS 5.3 by using a 4GB USB disk on an old PC that I used run a Debian on it. 
After a series of housework on the fresh system, I reboot the system using:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After that, the machine did not reboot successfully instead of directly powering down.

When I started the machine, after the BIOS, then GRUB.... But the GRUB gave this:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: file not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Then I googled around and did find some information on [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=76113). As the post said, I did the following in an attempt to wake up the machine.

First, I entered:

```
ls
```

then I received:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
```

and the last two partitions seems to be the ones in the USB disk.

Second, I entered:

```
ls (hd0)/
```

and received:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
```

I `ls`-ed the rest and get:

```
ls (hd0,msdos3)/
./ ../ lost+found/ home/ boot/ sys/ proc/ var/ tmp/ dev/ etc/ root/ selinux/ usr/ bin/ lib/ media/ mnt/ opt/ sbin/ srv/ misc/
```

and

```
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
./ ../ lost+found/ grub/ memtest86+-1.65 message initrd-2.6.18-128.el5.img System.map-2.6.18.el5 config-2.6.18-128.el5 symvers-2.6.18-128.el5.gz vmlinuz-2.6.18-128.el5
```

Then I followed the advice exactly on the very post to do this:

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/grub
```

and

```
set root=(hd0,msdos3)
```

After the settings, I entered:

```
insmod normal
```

and got:

```
error: file not found.
```

Could any one help me? I'm stucked....

Comment: googling around found this: http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ReinstallGRUB anyway what grub do you have?

Comment: @maniat1k 0.97, perhaps. Because I couldn't get into the system at this time. :(

Comment: @maniat1k your tip seems useful, but I should download a copy of the livecd....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW: 5.9 is the current CentOS-version.
You should start a rescue CD (or image) and reinstall grub.

In your case this is propably (after starting the grub-cli):

- root (hd0,msdos3)
- setup (hd0,msdos3)
- quit